# Visual C++ | qualifier must be a base class of "Foo"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does the following code

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool std::operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&);
};
```

comes up as an error ' qualifier must be a base class of "Foo" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a different (maybe more reasonable) error message [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/643744cfbb4ef586):

> ```
> main.cpp:4:48: error: invalid use of '::'
>      bool std::operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&);
>                                             ^
> ```

1. You cannot arbitrarily overload binary operator function as class member operator functions (see [Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)).
2. You cannot do this referencing the `std` namespace

What you probably wanted is

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool operator==(const Foo&) const;
};
```

---

If you're really sure you want to overload this in the `std::` namespace, you can write:

```
namespace std {
    bool operator==(const Foo& op1, const Foo& op2) {
        return op1.operator==(op2);
    }
}
```

or simply overload the binary `operator==()` function in the global namespace:

```
bool operator==(const Foo& op1, const Foo& op2) {
    return op1.operator==(op2);
}
```

Comment: ty, the std was an accident and on reflection idk why it was there, that error message is also a lot clearer ty

Answer (score 0):

In-class binary `operator`s have an implicit `Foo const &` as the left-hand side. Thus, you should only include one `Foo const &` as a parameter, not two.

edit: also, as mentioned in the other answer, you would have to drop the `std::` in this case too.